# BIND nslookup not resolving Azure, dig is fine

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Set up a pair of DNS sinkholes for my organization following the SANS document (http://handlers.sans.org/gbruneau/docs/DNS_Sinkhole_setup.pdf). Both are behaving the same when it comes to the following

My nslookup and dig results for azure.microsoft.com are different, nslookup not resolving.

nslookup:

```
root@SINK01:~# nslookup azure.microsoft.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find azure.microsoft.com: NXDOMAIN
```

dig:

```
root@SINK01:~# dig azure.microsoft.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.8-P4 <<>> azure.microsoft.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 1389
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;azure.microsoft.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
azure.microsoft.com.    34      IN      CNAME   azure.microsoft.com.nsatc.net.
azure.microsoft.com.nsatc.net. 220 IN   CNAME   acom-prod-uswest-01.azurewebsites.net.
acom-prod-uswest-01.azurewebsites.net. 1663 IN CNAME waws-prod-bay-013.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
windows.net.            600     IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. 2 10800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 24 09:56:10 PDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 247
```

/etc/named.conf

```
   options {
       directory "/var/named";
       version "my own";
       allow-transfer {"none";};
       allow-recursion {192.168.0.0/16; 10.0.0.0/8; localhost;};
       forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
       query-source address * port 53;
       listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
};

    zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "caching-example/named.root";
};

include "/etc/rndc.key";
include "/var/named/site_specific_sinkhole.conf";
include "/var/named/entire_domain_sinkhole.conf";
include "/var/named/custom_wildcard_sinkhole.conf";
include "/var/named/custom_single_sinkhole.conf";

zone "localhost" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/localhost.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "caching-example/named.local";
        allow-update { none; };
};

controls {
       inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
               allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
 };
```

resolv.conf

```
root@SINK01:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.168.87
```

debug nslookup:

```
root@SINK01:~# nslookup azure.microsoft.ocm -d2
setup_system()
ndots is 1.
copy_server_list()
make_server(127.0.0.1)
make_server(192.168.168.87)
lock_lookup dighost.c:3750
success
start_lookup()
setup_lookup(0x223a258)
resetting lookup counter.
cloning server list
clone_server_list()
make_server(127.0.0.1)
make_server(192.168.168.87)
using root origin
recursive query
add_question()
starting to render the message
done rendering
create query 0x7fe864505018 linked to lookup 0x223a258
create query 0x7fe864505268 linked to lookup 0x223a258
do_lookup()
send_udp(0x7fe864505018)
bringup_timer()
have local timeout of 1
working on lookup 0x223a258, query 0x7fe864505018
sockcount=1
recving with lookup=0x223a258, query=0x7fe864505018, sock=0x7fe8645054b0
recvcount=1
sending a request
unlock_lookup dighost.c:3752
lock_lookup dighost.c:2398
success
send_done()
sendcount=0
check_if_done()
list empty
unlock_lookup dighost.c:2429
recv_done()
lock_lookup dighost.c:3172
success
recvcount=0
lookup=0x223a258, query=0x7fe864505018
before parse starts
after parse
next_origin()
following up azure.microsoft.ocm
printmessage()
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find azure.microsoft.ocm: NXDOMAIN
returning with rcode == 0
still pending.
cancel_lookup()
check_if_done()
list empty
clear_query(0x7fe864505268)
clear_query(0x7fe864505018)
sockcount=0
check_next_lookup(0x223a258)
try_clear_lookup(0x223a258)
destroy
freeing server 0x7fe8580008e8 belonging to 0x223a258
freeing server 0x7fe858001108 belonging to 0x223a258
start_lookup()
check_if_done()
list empty
shutting down
dighost_shutdown()

done, and starting to shut down
cancel_all()
lock_lookup dighost.c:3766
unlock_lookup dighost.c:3651
success
unlock_lookup dighost.c:3809
destroy_libs()
freeing task
freeing taskmgr
lock_lookup dighost.c:3841
success
flush_server_list()
freeing commctx
freeing socketmgr
freeing timermgr
destroy DST lib
detach from entropy
unlock_lookup dighost.c:3894
Removing log context
Destroy memory
```

Comment: Post you /etc/resolv.conf also if you can

Comment: added resolv.conf, note 192.168.168.87 is its own IP

Comment: OK I was thinking of a search directive that could mess things up. One way to debug nslookup is to `nslookup -d2` and see what gives.

Comment: Here is what I get when I use the debug mode you noted... too long, will add to original post.

Answer (score 0):

`dig` uses the OS's DNS resolution library. `nslookup` uses its own, including potentially caching responses like `NXDOMAIN`.  For a while `nslookup` was considered a deprecated tool to be avoided in favor of other tools like `dig`. [Bind 9.9.0 changed that](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00496/0/BIND-9.9.0a3-Release-Notes.htm) (text search for `1700.`), however, and `nslookup` is apparently in a slightly-less-sucky state.

What you should do is make sure you have `nslookup` that was compiled at or after Bind 9.9.0. Then you should ask yourself "Why do I care about `nslookup` vs `dig`?" If you don't have a very specific and detailed answer, stick with `dig`.

---

<sub><sub>*Fiiiiiine*, if you really want to tweak around with nslookup, you should flush any local resolver's cache, such as ncsd or dnsmasq, or any OS specific DNS cache flushing mechanism such as sudo service dns-clean restart on certain versions of Ubuntu. Specific details of determining if there's even a DNS caching tool on the host, and how to flush it, is left as an exercise for the reader.</sub></sub>

Comment: To roll this back a bit, this is *going to be* setup as a DNS sinkhole. Our Domain Controller DNS servers will use it as their main forwarders for anything outside the company.  However in testing when it is setup like this, the DC DNS servers are unable to resolve azure.microsoft.com. 

nslookup and dig are the test i know to do and found this discrepancy.

if there are any addl tests i can do, believe me, i am open.

Comment: @JoeChenot What verison of bind-utils is on that host? Ultimately, to roll my own thoughts back a bit, you should look at the logs of the resolver to solve this, which would be the BIND server process, based on what I see of the SANS document. Yes, nslookup is part of BIND's package of tools, so that's a good start, but somehow the resolver itself isn't returning the right  response, so you need to crank debug logging up on it, as well as possibly put a packet capture on the interface listening for DNS traffic.